# Nodejs Stripe Webhooks

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am trying to create a stripe webhook for sending a notification to user email (not customer) every time a customer adds credit card to his account. Talked with stripe support team but, the only information they gave me was too implement it through [stripe webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks).

Stripe has some notification that we can enable and that will send notifications to user email but, it does not have a notification for when customer adds credit card details to his account and I am trying to implement that. Thanks in advance

I've already installed ngrok to run the webhook but, I do not know how to set up enpoint and create the webhook to send notifications to user

Answer (score 1):

You can sign in stripe, Navigation to Webhooks in left dashboard. And then create a webhook endpoint with ngrok host and your webhook API route. Example,
you create an webhook endpoint API like POST /api/v1/webhooks/stripe => Your webhook endpoint is: `https://ngrok.abc/api/v1/webhooks/stripe`
[Click here to redirect to stripe webhooks page](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/webhooks)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "sending a notification to user email (not customer)" but Stripe generally won't send emails to your users.

You'd have to implement sending an email on card update yourself. Have a look at implementing webhooks (https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/setup) and then listening for the `customer.source.created` event (https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-customer.source.created).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Paul Asjes, what I want is, a notification come to my email whenever someone adds credit card. I went through their documentation, what will be helpful for me is the right flow. right now I am thinking of implementing it 
1. Create an endpoint from stripe side
2. Create a webhook from my server side (don't know how)
3. finding out from stripe side how to trigger an email based on that event

would that be the right flow?

Comment: What you'd do is: 1. Follow the link on setting up webhooks I posted above 2. Setup your webhooks in your dashboard to listen for `customer.source.created` https://dashboard.stripe.com/webhooks 3. When you get the webhook event on your server, use something like nodemailer https://nodemailer.com/about/ to send yourself an email.

Comment: Thank you @Paul Asjes, I will go through the steps

Answer (score 0):

Will a Slack notification work for you? Here’s an automation I created using Pipedream’s free service that listens for Stripe's `customer.source.created` event (based on @Paul Asjes suggestion) and sends a message to Slack:

https://pipedream.com/@pravin/send-message-to-slack-when-payment-method-added-in-stripe-p_7NClk5

To use it:

1. Fork the template
2. [Create an incoming webhook URL in Slack](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks) and add it to the Pipedream workflow
3. Copy the Pipedream endpoint and set it as the webhook URL for `customer.source.created` events in Stripe

I hope that's helpful! I confirmed that it works with a test event from Stripe. If the notification has to an email, do you use any email services like Sendgrid?

Comment: I created a modified workflow on Pipedream to send an email using Sendgrid -- you can check it out here:

https://pipedream.com/@pravin/send-email-when-payment-method-added-in-stripe-p_ZJCbx5

To use it:

1. Fork the template

2. Copy the Pipedream endpoint and set it as the webhook URL for customer.source.created events in Stripe

3. Complete the fields in the Pipedream workflow (including configuring the Sendgrid API key) and save it